What options are there in Tailwind CSS for applying styles to the custom classes of a pre-built component?
I have a text editor in a MERN project where I am trying to change the z-index (and color eventually) of parts of its UI and cannot find a method to do so that makes me happy.
There is an obvious solution, accessing the classes with their selector in your stylesheet:
@layer utilities {
    .tox.tox-silver-sink.tox-tinymce-aux {
        z-index: 100000 !important;
    }
}

To me though, having the styles in a different file and using traditional CSS kind of defeats the main purpose of using Tailwind.
Are there any options out there to avoid that issue and keep all the styles to the className of the component?

Having some custom classes in another css file does not kill tailwind, it is just wanting to have a better classlist, for example you want to style a button with tailwind and that's something that will be shared in the whole project, do you prefer to have the long classlist in every button or just a btn classname which is pre defined in a custom css file

You just wanna change the Z-index?

@Rawand the main purpose of tailwind is to not have to have your CSS in a separate file allowing for better readability and development. Alternatives to using your index.css file would be nice here.

no bro, there are somethings you have to add manually

If your component allows, you could try adding the important flag to the className attributes of the component e.g. !z-40 so it take precedence over the rest.
The MDN docs say, this flag is used to make an individual property and value pair the most specific rule, thereby overriding the normal rules of the cascade, including normal inline styles.
You can read more about it here --> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Cascade_and_inheritance

This doesn't work unfortunately, I have tried it, I appreciate it though. The z-index is being applied to dropdown boxes and popups that are displaying behind the main component, hence the need for editing the index.css file and not using className.
